# how to use bootstrap object in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I am facing the issue while using the bootstrap object in my `ReactJS` project. the code is working properly in simple `HTML , CSS with JQuery` but it gives the error in React. the code is in following.
the header file is

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'
```

and the code in useEffect is

```
document
    .querySelectorAll(".dropdown-hover, .dropdown-hover-all .dropdown")
    .forEach((dd) => {
        dd.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
            let toggle = e.target.querySelector(":scope>[data-bs-toggle='dropdown']");
            if (!toggle.classList.contains("show")) {
                bootstrap.Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(toggle).toggle();
                dd.classList.add(CLASS_NAME);
                bootstrap.Dropdown.clearMenus();
            }
        });

        dd.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (e) {
            let toggle = e.target.querySelector(":scope>[data-bs-toggle='dropdown']");
            bootstrap.Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(toggle).toggle();
        });
    });
```

when it render then it gives me the error `ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined`. I figured out it that this issue is occur where I use the bootstrap. I used many way to resolve this issue but unable to resolve this problem. anyone can give me some solution to fix this issue?